# Assign line in text file to a string

Tags: c#, file-io, adventure

I'm making a simple text adventure in C# and I was wondering if it was possible to read certain lines from a .txt file and assign them to a string.

I am aware of how to read all the text from a .txt file but how exactly would I assign the contents of certain lines to a string?

Comment: How do you decide which lines?

Comment: If you know how to get the text already then your question is how to get an element of an array

Comment: @Sayse: Not necessarily - he or she could also be reading all the file contents (i.e. all lines) into a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) method?

It returns an array of lines from which you can choose your desired line.

So for eg, if you wish to choose the 3rd line (Assuming you have 3 lines in the file):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

string myThirdLine= lines[2];
```

Comment: I have tried the ReadAllLines method except I am unfamiliar with how I can actually choose a certain line.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest (and cheapest in terms of memory consumption) is [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
String stringAtLine10 = File.ReadLines(path).ElementAtOrDefault(9);
```

Note that it is `null` if there are less than 10 lines in the file. See: [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx).

It's just the concise version of a `StreamReader` and a counter variable which increases on every line.

Answer (score 0):

As an advanced alternative: [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) plus some LINQ:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(myFilePath).Where(MyCondition).ToArray();
```

where `MyCondition`:

```
bool MyCondition(string line)
{
   if (line == "something")
   {
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to load all lines atonce

```
using(StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(path))
{
String line;
while((line=reader.ReadLine())!=null)//process temp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example how you can assign the lines to a string, you can't decide which line is which via fields, you have to select them yourself.
which is the line of the string you want to assign.
For example, you want line one, you define which as one and not zero, you want line eight, you define which with eight.

```
string getWord(int which)
{
    string readed = "";
    using (Systen.IO.StreamReader read = new System.IO.StreamReader("PATH HERE"))
    {
       readed = read.ReadToEnd(); 
    }
    string[] toReturn = readed.Split('\n');
    return toReturn[which - 1];
}
```